# CakePHP 3 advanced Query Not Null with strange "QueryExpression" error?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am putting together a small mailing application within my application, and have run into a strange error - even just following the instructions for the advanced queries. I need to get -just- the mailboxes that are named:

```
    $CoreMailboxes = TableRegistry::get('CoreMailboxes');
    $query = $CoreMailboxes->find()
        ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
            return $exp->isNotNull('name');
        });
    $query->hydrate(false);
    return $query->toArray();
```

This is a near duplicate, sans "hydrate: false", of the example in the Cake Cookbook. However, it's giving me an error of

```
   Argument 1 passed to App\Model\Table\CoreMailboxesTable::App\Model\Table\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\QueryExpression, instance of Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression given
```

The query in the Cookbook is this:

```
    $query = $cities->find()
        ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
            return $exp->isNotNull('population');
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to query rows where a column value 'IS NOT NULL' ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get boxes that have names versus those that don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use the query expression for such a simple query..
You can just put the 'IS NOT NULL' in the where...
Now to re-use the query and create a more usable finder(), expressions may be more useful

```
$result = $this->Table->find()
  ->where([
     'TableName.column_name IS NOT NULL'
   ])->toArray();
```

Comment: This turned out to be the solution: $query->where(['name IS NOT' => null]); - thanks.

Comment: When using the non-expression variant it should be `'... IS NOT' => null` as shown in Merlin's comment, otherwise the query builder/compiler will treat the snippet as raw SQL, which comes with certain negative side effects, like for example not being able to apply possible auto-quoting.

Comment: It's all about context. If creating a re-usable finder or chainable query method then expressions should be used, but for something this simple and ad-hoc, using SQL operators in your conditions is perfectly acceptable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the instance definition's of your first argument, the [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data) is clear:

> The passed anonymous function will receive an instance of \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression as its first argument, and \Cake\ORM\Query as its second

Maybe you dont set the correct namespaces of this class, try this:

```
<?php 

use \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression as QueryExp;

//more code

//more code
    ->where(function (QueryExp $exp, Query $q) {
//more code
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter today same error.
Try to add

```
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;
```

at beginning of your controller. It's help in my case.
I also try kip's answer but it doesn't work in my case